# How do you replace element with its own content in IE?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, svg

Chrome passes `element.html(element.html())`, but IE throughs an error.

That's my only solution to redrawing an SVG eleemnt that isn't willing to show itself in USE tag after being lazy loaded to the document.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with hiding and re-showing the SVG element?
You could try

```
element.hide();
```

followed by

```
element.show();
```

This would sort of redraw the SVG and you would not need to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: I remember to have worked on an issue where markers on an SVG element were not being updated in IE. I fixed that by redrawing those markers instead of redrawing the complete SVG. If I may ask, why do you need to redraw the SVG?

Comment: The problem was solved somehow by appending the downloaded svg itself, rather than establishing a new symbol based on it. I guess that it didn't work before, because I tried to minpulate the "id" attribute on the symbol. That still leaves the question: Is IE failing with the html replacement because it involves an SVG element?

Comment: No idea, IE does usually fail at what other browsers do like a breeze :)